# After my Korean C-4 visa expires, can I re-enter immediately as a visa-free national?

Tags: us-citizens, south-korea, visa-free-entry

I hava question in regards to my current work visa in Seoul South Korea. I am a US citizen in Seoul, South Korea, on a C-4 work visa that will expire next week.

If don't have a employer to renew or reapply for the C-4 visa to stay longer, can I do a visa run to another country and just come back to South Korea? Visa-free entry for 90 days as a tourist would let me stay longer until I can obtain the right paperwork. I would then leave and apply for a new work visa if I decide to stay and work in Korea.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange! This question might be better suited for expatriates.stackexchange.com, which deals with issues related to long-term immigration.